# How to add a displacement map on a plane using procedural textures with a layer mask

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I have mixed two textures together using black and white values from a noise texture which is connected to a color ramp.
How can I apply a displacement map on a plane so that either the texture "A" or "B" is the limiting factor that determines
which parts are affected by the displacement modifier within a plane? I want to use a mask layer to adjust the intensity
of the displacement with a noise texture, but at the same time limit it to only some parts of the texture combination.

I have applied a rough displacement on my scene which covers the whole plane, but I'm asking this beacuse I want to
add some fine details with two (displacement) modifiers. I know you can assign vertex groups to mark off the affected area,
but in my case that's not possible, for you can't see any textures in a vertex select mode and it forces you to select them
randomly.

There's a link below to give you a better idea about the problem. Areas which I want to add some extra displacement to are
marked as red.

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NHszZHPR_1OVFEWEt2UkdON28/view?pli=1

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution **not** using the Displace Modifier:

In Cycles, using the **Displacement Input Socket** on the material Output, you can control the displacement with a combination of texture nodes.

In this example of a simple (subdivided and UV unwrapped) plane, the wave texture is combined with a voronoi texture using an image texture of the letter A as the mix factor. In other words: the voronoi texture will only displace the parts with the letter A.

[image]

[image]

Note that this is a true 3D displacement of the geometry, not just a bump map:

[image]

As of version **2.75**, this is only possible using the **Experimental Feature set** in the Render controls

[image]

and enabling **True** as the **Displacement Method** for the mesh.

[image]

Comment: I did what you suggested and had no idea until about a week later that it wasn't working as it should (I didn't have access to my computer and checked your answer pretty carelessly). But anyway, the case is that the displacement of the geometry show up only in the cycles. When I render the scene it just disappears. 

In addition to that I'm having difficulties to get rid of sharp shadows which cause trouble around protruding and patchy areas. So far I have tried to subdivide the plane, add some extra lightning and recalculated the normals but without much of success. Any ideas?

Comment: can you upload your file?

Comment: Here you go: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NHszZHPR_1aE4wTE9sYVdYU0U/view?usp=sharing".  Just rotate the sun lamp something like 75-85 degrees and you'll get some nasty distorted shadows.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work on top of the displace modifier. I'll play with it a bit and see.

Comment: Apply the displacement modifiers. In object mode apply scale on your plane (Ctrl+ A->Scale) so that the scale of the plane is 1. In the node editor play with the multiply factors on the multiply node before the displacement. To update the deformation exit and reenter Rendered mode. If the file deforms in preview but doesn't render: disable experimental and enable it again (it is indeed an experimental feature, not fully supported yet) If the displacement is too sharp you need more subdivisions on your plane, and maybe even a subsurf modifier. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/374/

Comment: It's now starting to look what I had in mind, but I still wasn't able to fix the blocky / disorted shadows issue. The problem won't go away by applying subdivision and a subsurf modifier. What they do is that they only make those broken shadows appear more frequently and smaller in size. Subdivision also makes the displacement pattern to rearrange, so I have to make adjustments for the multiply factors each time. Here's another pic: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NHszZHPR_1aEJfTVprd0x3Rk0/view?usp=sharing. This might go little off the original subject, so should I make a new post about it?

Comment: make a new post to keep things organized

Answer (score 2):

I dont think is currently possible.

**Why?**

Because there is no Texture node editor for the Displacement modifier.

---

[image]

You'll need to mask the two textures with the procedural texture (excactly how as been done for the diffuse color), make some tweak an put this **custom** texture, created with the built-in node tree, in the Displace modifier.

This is not currently possible (2.75a) because, as said [here](https://developer.blender.org/T32759) (as far as I know things has not changed yet about this) there are some issue implementing this, so you'll not see a Displacement modifier slot next to the four under the arrow in the image above.

[image]

and none of the provided texture type is capable to be mixed with another as needed.

---

[image]

You could try to mask the displace modifier with a flipped copy and a Shrinkwrap modifier with limit enabled...but there are a lot of limitations in this kind of approach, so I won't suggest you.

Comment: You can also try baking the textures and combine them in Gimp or PS if you don't really need procedural.