# Mixing Displacement Procedural Texture

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Is there a way to mix procedural textures (like clouds, voronio, etc) for the Displace modifier?

I managed to work with nodes (like in cycles) to produce a mix using the Brush tab in Node editor and it does actually show a preview when selecting it in the Textures tab in Properties editor, but has no effect in the modifier.

Thanks

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34108/how-to-add-a-displacement-map-on-a-plane-using-procedural-textures-with-a-layer/34271#34271 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/multiple-texture-displacements-mapping-in-one-scene/44927#44927 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45875/how-to-mix-procedural-textures-for-a-natural-waves-of-sand-displacement-effect/45896#45896

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with newest Blender versions (as I remember from 2.78 and up).

[image: disp]

First of all you'll need to turn on **Experimental features** (1) and select under **Material** tab **Displacement** as **True** (2). You can use **Both** but mixing **Displacement** with **Bump** gives weird results. Next step is to add **Subdivision Surface modifier** with **Adaptive** checked.

You can check whole tutorial about it here: [Introduction to Microdisplacements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRzzaRvVDng)