# A PBR map with Principled shader doesn't add value to the object

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor, pbr

I'm trying to create the ground covered with leaves, everything seems fine, but it's completely flat. I suppose a normal map is in charge of it, but I have no idea how to fix it.
 There are screenshots of top view, side view and a material setup.

[image: A view from top]
[image: A view from the side]
[image: Materail setup]

Comment: You probably want displacement: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45873/blender-cycles-true-displacement/45874#45874

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work/50442#50442 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34108/how-to-add-a-displacement-map-on-a-plane-using-procedural-textures-with-a-layer/34271#34271

Answer (score 1):

The normal map is ok, it only changes the light reflections according to the faked angle of incidence, but it actually doesn't move any vertex of the mesh. Maybe what you are looking for is a displacement effect: you can subdivide your mesh (the more subdivided, better the result but heavier the mesh) and add a displace modifier, using your specular map as input and trimming the strenght value to a quite low level: in this way you will have a real vertices roughness, that may help the realistic effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem can't be solved in this way, because the texture is too complicated. If to use a displacement modifier the plane has to be subdivided to many times, what loades Blender too much.

Comment: What you say is true, but the displacement method is very commonly used: many light informations are dirven by diffuse color, specular and normal map, so a little, not complete nearly subdivided displacement just helps the material's beavebility, even if subdivision is far too little to be "enough" by itself. Microdisplacement uses the same approach but it adds the adaptativity, so objects near to the camera are subdivided more times than far ones (very clever trick!)

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this problem is to use a microdisplacement.
 So I've just added a displacement map to a material *displacemnt* input, turned *experimental render feature set* on, made displacement *True* in material settings and added an *adaptive* subsurface modifier.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late and this isn't really related but something that could affect that is specular, if you are using a PBR workflow there is no benefit in using a Specular since you already have Roughness/Gloss